# Android Studio Logcat not showing console.log messages

Tags: angular, cordova, android-studio, logcat

I am very new to android studio. I have the source code of an android mobile app that is developed using Angular. I am trying to put some debug messages to understand the code by putting console.log statements but Logcat is not showing these messages instead it says "**exec() call to unknown plugin: Console**". What am I missing please?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Go to **File--> Invalidates caches/restart**
after restarting it will work .

Comment: No, that didn't work for me. The thing is it's not recognizing"console", it says "exec() call to unknown plugin: Console".